# Get only consumers from an operation that has a user attached with Eloquent in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a list of meters:

```
ID, name, user_id 
1, meter1, 4
2, meter2, NULL
3, meter3, 5
```

and consumers from an Operation:

Operation Class:

```
public function consumers(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->users()->role(User::CONSUMER);
    }
```

Relations:

- An operation hasMany users
- A meter belongs to a user
- a user hasMany roles

I would like to get only consumers from an operation that has a user attached.

In my example, it should just return meter 1 and 3.

I just don't know how to do it with Eloquent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

#### Updated as requested by topic owner:

```php
public function consumers(): HasMany 
{
    return $this->users()->role(User::CONSUMER)->whereHas('meter', function($query) {
        $query->whereNotNull('user_id'); 
    }); 
}
```

#### My personal answer:

```php
$consumers = Operation::with(['consumers' => function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('meter', function($qry) {
        $qry->whereNotNull('user_id');
    });
}])->get();

//Or better:

Class User extends Model
{
    ...

    public function existing_meters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Meter::class)->whereNotNull('user_id');
    }
}

//then you can use it:

$consumers = Operation::with('consumers.existing_meters')->get();
```

Comment: the problem is $this refer to operation model. I added relations in my question.

Comment: @Juliatzin can a user have multiple meter?

Comment: @Juliatzin try that.

Comment: I solved thanks to your answer with: public function consumers(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->users()->role(User::CONSUMER)
            ->whereHas('meter', function ($query) {
                $query->whereNotNull('user_id');
            });
    }

Please update your answer so I can accept it ! Thanks !

Comment: @Juliatzin I updated my answer with another solution. You can check that too.